I left my dog on a boat, then died. Dog was gone when I returned. Can I get it back?
I left my dog on the boat. I don't remember if it was sitting or not, but it did not return when I respawned at home base. It had a name tag, I didn't see the name tag icon in any direction.
I checked what I think was the game logs and didn't see any statement saying he died. The boat was far from my home base but I was sure that I came to the right spot when I returned, I screenshotted the coordinates for the location.
Since this whole story happened a while ago, I don't remember if I saw the boat or not when I returned, but I was sure that I found the right spot because the boat with my dog was over a shipwreck where I drowned in when exploring, and I found that shipwreck and the identical surrounding landscape when I returned after drowning.
Is the dog lost forever, or can I find it somehow?

Are you willing/able to use minecraft commands to get your Dog back, or do you want a pure gameplay answer?
